# Telegram still knows my location after using a VPN

Tags: vpn, telegram

I connected to a VPN and turned off location but telegram still show my country in registration form. How this is possible?

Comment: To use any app, you still must use some connection point, which identifies itself when you use the network. Every bit of information on the internet identifies FROM/TO info for normal routing, even in generalized form.

Answer (score 1):

there are different methods to get the user's current location in android. If you have turned off your location  it checks your last known location from your phone

Try changing your current location in maps by using/downloading FAKE GPS from play store.

Hope this helps.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Smartphone with SIM card inserted and unlocked, Telegram can simply query the network operator info (which includes the country) of your SIM card.

Answer (score 0):

I used a VPN([Hola](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.hola&hl=en)) to route through Switzerland and then I changed the location using [Fake GPS Location - Hola](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.hola.gpslocation&hl=en) to the same area the VPN was routed to (according to Telegram's check based on my IP). I also turned off my mobile data. I assume Telegram is keeping track of *when* the account was used *where* and then they just show the last location available in their database if the sudden change in location doesn't make sense.

Here you can see they got my location wrong:

[image: Telegram's message after I logged in]

Also when sending my location in a chat they show the fake location I set. Unfortunately, when searching for friends or groups nearby this is not the case.